# How to display uploaded image to App-Visual Studios 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

So I added an image to the project:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVxPM.png)

How can I make it display in the app? sorry I know this is a stupid question, I am new to app dev. I tried to import a image control from the Visual Studio toolbox and hoped there would be some kind of drag and dop kind of thing. the code for the Image control:

```
<Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="174" Margin="69,148,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="229"/>
    <ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="150" Margin="110,172,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165">
        <ListView.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Mobile Applications\Logo\logo.png"/>
        </ListView.Background>
    </ListView>
```

I am using Visual Basics to develop the app.

Comment: I'm guess you just want the picture to be displayed in an "Image" box yeah?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got no idea why you are using a ListView to display an image however in order to display an image using the "Image" tool, you need to set the source via XAML like this

`<Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="183" Margin="154,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96" Source="Images\Man.png"/>`

Please note, I created a folder called "Images"

Of course there are others ways to add an image without XAML, but this is a good starting point for you I think.

P.S you will need to drag the "Image" Tool to your application, also i tried this using Windows Phone, it maybe different depending on what Framework you are using, but shouldn't be too hard to work out.

Happy Coding!